# How can I start a Minecraft server from the web?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

How can I start a Minecraft server on a server that has a web server?
For example those control panels that start servers when the server is offline. I know they can execute a shell script but how. If someone could provide me with some example code.

Comment: You said "server" 5 times in your first 2 sentences.

Answer (score 4):

So, I guess you have a Linux VPS or dedicated server, where you can install whatever you want? Good.

For this, we use the bukkit server.

Here are some [instructions](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Setting_up_a_server):

```
1. Download CraftBukkit's latest build: CraftBukkit - Recommended Build 
2. Put the .jar in a folder, for this example we'll use a generic one: ~/craftbukkit 
3. Move to the above directory in terminal with 'cd ~/craftbukkit' 
4. Create a new file in the minecraft folder and name it craftbukkit.sh 
5. Edit the file and paste this into it:
```

> #!/bin/sh
>    BINDIR=$(dirname "$(readlink -fn "$0")")
>    cd "$BINDIR"
>    java -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar -o true

```
6. Make the file executable, either by running "chmod +x ~/craftbukkit/craftbukkit.sh" in a terminal, or by changing the permissions in the file's properties. 
7. Then, in terminal, type '~/craftbukkit/craftbukkit.sh' to run to start the server.  
8. When you're done playing around, issue the "stop" command in console.
```

You can run bukkit like described above, but there are other options - you can run the server permanently with an [init script](https://github.com/Ahtenus/minecraft-init) or run it with an [ASCII interface](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/ascii-bukkit-menu/)

EDIT:

Reread your question, could be that I misunderstood. So here is another link to something that should be what you need - [Bukkit Webby](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/bukkit-webby/)

> Bukkit Webby is a lightweight web administration that is easy and fast
>   to setup It's made of two components :
>
> WebbyBukkitPlugin is a Bukkit Plugin that interacts with Bukkit, read your server log, find all online users, etc.
>
> WebbyRTK is a RTK module that interacts with RemoteToolkit and run the webserver. Even if Bukkit has been shutdown, the webserver will persists and allow you to restart Bukkit.
>
> Current Features
>
> - Server administration based on Bukkit Remote Toolkit (Start / Stop / Restart / Reload)
> - Online configuration files
> - Online server log
> - Backup management (manual backup, automated restore)
> - Easy installation : drop the jars and files as any bukkit plugins, setup port, login and password for webby and RTK, and you are done !
> - NO APACHE NEEDED !

There are tons of other [bukkit plugins](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/?category=website-administration) for website administration. If my suggestion is not what you want, you can check the plugins.